# She has been for 3 hours.?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

There is a scenario like this. There is a woman in a restaurant. The restaurant owner asks her to leave but she doesn't leave. The restaurant owner calls the police. When the police arrive, he tells the police: ***She has been for 3 hours.***

Second scenario: A waiter in a restaurant serves a customer. The customer gets up and leaves after a certain time, but the waiter does not notice this. A friend of the customer asks the waiter about that person. The waiter's answer is: ***She has been for 3 hours.*** I haven't seen her go

She has been three hours ? What's the difference between these two?

Comment: She has been _what_ for three hours? Singing? Sleeping? Here? There?

Comment: It's missing something that a previous sentence must provide. "Has she taken up that table for more than 2 hours?" "She has been for 3 hours."

Comment: (1) She has been **here** for three hours." (2) Does the waiter mean "She was here for three hours"? If he didn't see her go, how does he know how long she was there for?

Comment: Did these sentences spontaneously appear? Did you make them up? Did you read them somewhere? Are they from ChatGPT?

Answer (score 2):

These sentences don't work.  They don't mean what you want them to mean.

The verb "be" is normally used as a linking verb.  It should have a complement, and "for three hours" doesn't link back to the subject.  You could say "She's been here for three hours" or "She's been sitting there for three hours" or something.  "She has been for three hours" is simply incorrect English.

Now, there is a fairly colloquial use  "She has been three hours", which is understood to mean "She has been away for three hours", usually with the implication that it has taken her three hours to do something, and she isn't finished yet. It's not particularly common.